# Limited Up-To-Ground Viewing

Tags: visible, ghost-blog

I want to lose an element in my site that appears to a certain place while scrolling down the site. However, I only want to do this by phone. I think I can do this with the @media tag but I don't know how to look up to a certain place and then lose it is there that can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the browser inspector and the option to resize the web browser to above and below the width of the phone size you're targeting. If you're using Google Chrome then there's a handy guide here on how to use the device mode in developer tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode

The other thing you'll need to do is to target the element in CSS and hide it depending on the browser size. The syntax will look something like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .the-class-name-value {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You'll need to replace the `640` part with the maximum browser size you want to target, and replace the `the-class-name-value` with the value of the `class` attribute on the actual element. Hope this helps!